# How do you monitor I/O on individual devices in windows?

Tags: windows, performance, monitoring, io, performance-monitor

Can anyone tell me if there's a handy little utility out there that will monitor and display the I/O charts for individual drives on windows?

On linux Gkrellm is great for this.

Comment: You might look into xperf, but writing a decent answer on this is outside my expertise since I barely ever actually use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What devices do you want to monitor?
There is a **perfmon.exe** out of the box from windows for system monitoring:

- USB: Average Bytes /Transfer
- Physical Disk: Average Disk Bytes/Transfer
- Network Interface: Bytes Total/ sec
- etc.

Screenshot (sorry that it is in Chinese environment)  : 
[image]

Comment: Thanks, I was familiar with perfmon.exe but hadn't realised it was able to moitor individual devices